# Robot Framework set Json Value to a list

Tags: json, robotframework

Writing some Robot Framework tests.

Using RIDE to test some Restful Web services.

For simplicity this is the basic JSON

```
  ${Rlist}  {"list" : []}
```

The code will generate a random number,  and I need to store that in the list. 
The best I think I have gotten is create a list, and try to store that value back into the JSON.

```
${listValue}    Create List    ${num}
${Rlist}    Set Json Value    ${Rlist}    /list    ${listValue}
```

I just get a 
TypeError: expected string or buffer

I have tried to convert the JSON to a dictionary, but I can't get that working either.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the list to String and removing unnecessary chars before parsing it to JSON will save your problem. Here is the complete code for your reference.

```
${Rlist}  Set Variable  {"list":[]}
${listValue}  Create List
:FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  5
\  ${random_number}  Generate Random String  8  [NUMBERS]
\  Append To List  ${listValue}  ${random_number}
${string_list}  Convert To String  ${listValue}
${string_list}  Remove String  ${string_list}  u
${string_list}  Replace String  ${string_list}  '  "
${Rlist}  Set Json Value  ${Rlist}  /list  ${string_list}
Log Json  ${Rlist}
```

Hope this helps.